# Make blender verticles not move while posing

Tags: blender

I am totally new to blender. I know to create objects but rigging is lite problem to me. I downloaded male model with everything but problem is now when i move his arm (bend it with bones), his neck get off head (2 separated objects).

Here is the image what happens. What can i do?

Before:
[image: before]

After:
[image: after]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a bit hard to see, but if the head comes loose, then the problem is in the model. One could fix it by repairing the model, in mesh edit, make it one connected object, as a result of that, when changing the mesh(add and connect surfaces) the the weights of the orginal model wont work anymore on the model. So then you would need to reaply weights from bones to the meshmodel. 
As you said your totally new to blender, i think all those steps would be a bit to much (i have repaired meshes but i got 5 years of experience), for you repairing a model might be a bit too complex (its advanced stuff usually a few hours of blender work to fix something).
It might be much easier to startoff with correct models, you can get them at blendswap, or you could install the Bastioni addon, he's one of the MakeHuman creators and transformed that code into blender. Look for Bastioni and you get real good human models who you can pose.